# When the tcp slows-start starts?

Tags: networking, tcp, bytestream

For instance,the tcp connection is not established yet,after the connection establishment,the slowstarts begins,and the 3rd segment of the handshake already caries the data,so the question is when the slowstart will begin?It will begin with the 1 segment which contains the data(3 part of the handshake),or it will start simultaneously with the handshake?

Comment: It starts at the start.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming. Try http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Both peers set the [initial window](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5681#page-4) (IW) on initialisation based on their MSS and use it to advertise their window size to the peer.

Then, when the first data is transmitted along with the 3rd and final part of the handshake it can be sized up to the peers advertised IW.

Thus, the answer to your question is that slow start starts with the data transmitted along with the 3rd part of the handshake (if any) and the advertised window ramps up (or down) on both sides as data is exchanged.

It's all in RFC5681. The initial conditions are described on pages 3,4 and 5.